# Sort x-axis for sns.countplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am working my way through: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/exploratory-data-analysis-of-the-hotel-booking-demand-with-python-200925230106

In a bunch of the visualization outputs the sort order is off.  As I am working my way through each question, I have successfully fixed the sort order of every output -- until now.

For question #6, part two (Let’s see the stay duration trend for each hotel type.)  I am getting
the exact same output as is shown in the article. However, the x-axis is incorrectly sorted, and I am trying to fix it as I have all previous outputs.

Here is my code for question #6, including the first part where I fixed the sort order:

```
# 6. How long do people stay in the hotel?
df_not_canceled2 = df_not_canceled.copy()
total_nights = df_not_canceled2['stays_in_weekend_nights'] + df_not_canceled2['stays_in_week_nights']
x5, y5, z5 = get_count(total_nights, limit=10)

x5 = x5[[0, 2, 1, 3, 5, 6, 4, 8, 7, 9]]
y5 = y5[[0, 2, 1, 3, 5, 6, 4, 8, 7, 9]]
z5 = z5[[0, 2, 1, 3, 5, 6, 4, 8, 7, 9]]

plot(x5, y5, x_label='Number of Nights', y_label='Booking Percentage (%)', title='Night Stay Duration (Top 10)', figsize =(10, 5))
plt.show()

# The stay duration trend for each hotel type.
df_not_canceled2.loc[:, 'total_nights'] = df_not_canceled2['stays_in_weekend_nights'] + df_not_canceled2['stays_in_week_nights']
df_not_canceled2 = df_not_canceled2.sort_values(by=['total_nights']).reset_index(drop=True)

fig1, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))
ax.set_xlabel('No of Nights')
ax.set_ylabel('No of Nights')
ax.set_title('Hotel wise night stay duration (Top 10)')

sns.countplot(x='total_nights', hue='hotel', data=df_not_canceled2,
              order=df_not_canceled2['total_nights'].value_counts().iloc[:10].index, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

First I tried sorting the df by 'total_nights'.  The output did not change.  Then I sorted and reset the index (this is the current state of my code).  Still no change.

This is what I get (exactly the same as the article):
[image]

Notice the sort order of the x-axis (total_nights).  I want 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc., not 1, 3, 2, 4, 7, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out.  Had to remove .value_counts from the order parameter.

[image]